# Calling SSRS Drillthrough from client side asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using a ReportViewer in my ASP.NET website.
I would like to catch the Drillthrough element, show a context menu using jQuery and execute a Drillthrough with a different parameters according to user's choice in menu.
I'm able to catch the relevant Drillthrough and show the context menu, but now i'm facing a problem calling Drillthrough from client side - is this even possible?
Tried with static WebMethod but the reportViewer is **NOT** accessible from it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using ProcessingMode = Remote on your ReportViewer control.  If that's the case, then once you start the top-level report, it is out of your hands.  Though its never actually stated anywhere in MSDN, the ReportViewer events such as Drillthrough are ONLY available for ProcessingMode.Local.  You might be able to hack into the actual JavaScript the report uses, but it'd be just that - a hack.